# How do I add a virtual GPU into Qemu?

Tags: opengl, graphics, qemu

I was wondering how to go about adding a virtual GPU into Qemu? 
I have been told it involves adding a new graphics output module that uses OpenGL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create virtual hardware, kernel, qemu for Android Emulator in order to produce OpenGL graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762039/create-virtual-hardware-kernel-qemu-for-android-emulator-in-order-to-produce-op)

Comment: The Android emulator does it and is QEMU based, so you might want to look into it's source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762039/create-virtual-hardware-kernel-qemu-for-android-emulator-in-order-to-produce-o/38039398#38039398

Answer (score 4):

You probably refer to [Create virtual hardware, kernel, qemu for Android Emulator in order to produce OpenGL graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762039/create-virtual-hardware-kernel-qemu-for-android-emulator-in-order-to-produce-op/5763466#5763466)

The very first thing I suggest you do is reading the source code how commands to the virtual graphics adaptors already implemented are turned into graphical output. Then you should rewrite this, to use OpenGL commands instead. Once you got this you must literally *invent* a new, virtual GPU to offer the guest system. I'd not even attempt to emulate a GeForce or Radeon. GeForces are not publically documented anyway.

qemu doesn't provide a real kind of API for implementing a GPU. Of course there's some internal API for that, used to implement that VESA and S3 emulation, but a new GPU will require you to redo a lot of that again.

The virtual hardware should offer some I/O to pass drawing commands and data. In theory you could pass the full set OpenGL commands there. However OpenGL is hardware agnostic, whereas you actually implement "hardware", so you must find some balance there. Then in qemu you must implement that virtual hardware to execute the rendering commands apropriately.

Last but not least you must implement drivers for that virtual hardware, which will involve adding a new driver to Mesa and creating a driver for Xorg.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again datenwolf, you are a hero. I am starting this right now and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: You wouldn't by any chance be able to tell me which file in the Qemu source relates to the virtual graphics adaptors? I've been looking through it, specifically the hw folder, for the last half an hour and am a little puzzled

Comment: @Tomau000: It's been a very long time since I messed around with the qemu code. I think the best way to do this is using a tool like cscope or egypt (found here http://www.gson.org/egypt/ ) to trace back the data flow from the graphics output (just grep the sources for inclusion of SDL_video.h header). Then I'd start with replacing the use of SDL functions to draw stuff with calls to OpenGL (you can keep SDL for creating the window and handling input events). Once you got qemu so far that it uses OpenGL for graphics output, you've can start thinking about, how to pass 3D commands.

Comment: Thanks for all your input datenwolf. The steps suggested are over my head I think, it gets very confusing.
However i'd like to show you something that I came across.. http://code.google.com/p/nehe-android/downloads/list
This link contains an apk that someone has created which runs the nehe opengl tutorial's on the android emulator!! Do you think it contains the relevant material we have been discussing? i.e. kernal drivers and the rest?
Tom

Comment: ^ Woops, after looking through the source i've found that all it is is the tutorials ported onto opengl es..